# vb.net ClickOnce application deployment issue

Tags: .net, vb.net, deployment, frameworks, clickonce

Hi there I have an issue with my ClickOnce application deployment. The issue is that I built the application with the .net framework 4.5 and had that deployed. (all working fine!) But then I have downgraded the .net framework to version 2.0 then when I publish that version it still says:

```
The following prerequisites are required:   
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 (x86 and x64)
```

The reason I have downgraded to .net framework 2.0 is for compatibility reasons.

It's probably something simple that i'm missing?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@STiTCHiCKED : Check whether your project is running with Framework 2.0.

For that Right Click the project from solution explorer, Goto Properties, Check Application Tab, See if the Target framework is 2.0, if not set it.

Then Goto Publish Tab and Open Prerequisites option.
Select .Net framework 2.0 and untick other options if any.

Build the application and Publish.
Check if this helps..!!!

Comment: Spot on That's what I ended up doing in the end, only question tho is: Is there a Prerequisites for .net framework 2.0 as I don't have an option for .net framework 2.0? what would happen if the end user does not have .net 2.0 installed? will it install it!!

Comment: Give the least framework you have as pre-requisite. 
If the user does not have any of the framework in his machine, he will be asked to installed the one you selected as a Prerequisite.
Else, it won't work.

Please mark as answer, if the above answer helped you... Thanks